# Raspberry Pi 3 No wireless interfaces found

Tags: wifi, connection, internet

I have Raspberry Pi 3 and I tried to config for auto connect to wifi like this example

http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/

but when I finish, I got "No wireless interfaces found" when I click wifi symbol.
However if I comment them out and back to default config( no auto wlan0 ... ), my wifi is back.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the config files you changed with the commented out textincluded.

Comment: Can you explain **HOW** people find these obsolete tutorials and **WHY** they choose to follow them rather than the Official [Raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) instructions? Try [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: here is my interface config

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0
#auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet manual
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

#allow-hotplug wlan1
#iface wlan1 inet manual
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: @Milliways I'm very new in linux configuration I just follow my search

Comment: These details belong in your question (as requested) not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Restore Interfaces file. Then, connect to wifi manually and now into the interfaces file append this
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
      wpa-ssid {ssid}
      wpa-psk {password}

this work for me.

Lo dejo en español ya que mi ingles es malo y por ahi no se entiende que quise decir. Restaura el archivo interfaces como viene ni bien instalas el SO. Así vuelve a funcionar el receptor WiFi y podes conectarte a la red (yo lo hice mediante la interfaz grafica) Una vez conectado al Wifi que queremos que conecte automaticamente podemos modificar el archivo interfaces y ahora la proxima vez que prendamos va a funcionar.

Sorry for my bad English.